# Need to create a column in sharepoint that has attachments

Tags: sharepoint

I have created the below list in sharepoint with attachments enabled. When i add a new item I see the attachment option but I dont see a column for it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh3Ln.jpg)

And I want to sent an email to the approver to approve along with the file attachment that was added while creating the item. I added the link item and the item link decription dynamically as in the pic below. But it sends the whole list item instead of the document alone. So when the link is clicked the complete list items are displayed along with the attachment. I then have to click the attachment and then it will take me to the file. But I want the link to take me directly to the file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8gPp.jpg)

I checked youtube videos and they have the beginning column as a document file column with a document icon with upload option on the top. But I dont find any upload option in my sharepoint. The below image was taken fro a youtube video which has upload option

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REOqq.jpg)

I have made certain column inputs mandatory while adding a new item. Will that make a difference?

Answer (score 3):

Please following steps:

**Add Attachments on the list**

1.You can click on **+ Add column** and select **Show/hide columns**

[image]

2.On the Edit view columns panel, find and check the **Attachments** checkbox

[image]

3.Click on **Apply**

[image]

**Send email with attachments**

1.Create Microsoft Flow

[image]

2.Save and Test it

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I am able to add the attachment colum now. But the document name is not aoming up, it is just showing the attahcment symbol.

Comment: Another issue that came after adding the get attachments action was in the flow item created -> get item -> get attachments -> get attachment content -> start and wait approval -> switch -> case1 -> send email -> update item. In this update item I update a field from the response summary in the start and approval with the dynamic content "completion date". But I cant find that dynamic content now which worked perfectly before. In the error flow it says switch cant choose from "body/outcome" but i have added only "outcome" in switch. Body was added in "start and approval".

Comment: Hi Nisha Balan. The Attachments column only indicates with an attachment icon whether the items has attachments or not. It does not show the detailed attachment. If someone wants to open the attachment, he/she still needs to open the list item.